# Win forms, how to assign a method to radio button when checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and Win forms so please be patient with me.

I have e radio buttons that has been written programatically. I want to update the value of which button is checked. Here is the code for one of the buttons

```
        RadioButton cab = new RadioButton();
        cab.Text = m_appContext.L10nManager.TranslateString("Modern");
        cab.Name = "Modern";
        cab.Location = new Point(15, 45);
        cab.AutoSize = true;
```

I want to assign a "method" when it is checked. So I go ahead add this to my radio button:

```
ca.Checked = m_appContext.EWSMode;
```

Here is the code for EWSMode:

```
    public enum EWSMode { Auto = 0, EWS = 1, Classical = 2 };
    EWSMode m_EWSMode = EWSMode.Auto;
    public EWSMode EWSMode
    {
        get { return m_EWSMode; }
        set { m_EWSMode = value; }
    }
```

Depending on which radio button is selected I want to set **m_EWSMode** to that value. So by default

```
EWSMode m_EWSMode = EWSMode.Auto;
```

When, say radio button EWS is selected I want to set **m_EWSMode** to EWS

At what point do I set/pass the new value to my EWSMode enum and how do I do it?
[image]

Comment: [RadioButton.CheckedChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The commented-out line of code right below it is what you're looking for.  Or at least a step in that direction.  It looks like `EWSMode` is an `enum`, not a method to be invoked.  So it's really not clear what you're even trying to do.

Comment: Depending on which radio button is selected I want to set m_EWSMode to that value. So by default "EWSMode m_EWSMode = EWSMode.Auto;". When say radio button EWS is selected I want to set m_EWSMode to EWS.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56382193/edit) instead of putting information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an EventHandler, like this:

```
ca.Checked += new System.EventHandler(EWSMode);
```

Note that EWSMode has to have the correct signature, taking `object` and `EventArgs` as parameters:

```
private void EWSMode(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If you want to set a variable's value according to what check is selected, you can subscribe them both to an event handler:

```
ca1.Checked += new System.EventHandler(EWSMode_Event);
ca2.Checked += new System.EventHandler(EWSMode_Event);
```

And then put the logic in `EWSMode_Event`:

```
private void EWSMode_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//When ca1 or ca2 gets checked, this event will be triggered. Here, you would
//set your m_EWSMode variable.
}
```

You can do the same thing using one event for each CheckBox:

```
ca1.Checked += new System.EventHandler(EWSMode_Event);

private void EWSMode_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //When ca1 gets checked, this event will be triggered.

    EWSMode m_EWSMode = EWSMode.EWS;
}
```

Comment: on this EWSMode method you wrote, how do I pass value to my get; set; ? I am guessing I have to call public EWSMode EWSMode
    {
        get { return m_EWSMode; }
        set { m_EWSMode = value; }
    } at some point to set value right?

Comment: Yep, check the edit and let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: thank you for your patience and dummy friendly answer!